# Looping through master sheet and filter out rows that are needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have created a script which I want to allow a user to select a file (Master File) and if a condition is a met I want to Copy the data to the excel workbook (which the script is run on) The code below shows the idea of what I am trying to do. Currently the if statement just checks if A2 contains the value 5. I want it to check each row in the column not just the one cell.

```
Sub copyData()
Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

 FolderPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS*),  
 *.XLS*", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
 Dim numTest As Integer

Filename = Dir(FolderPath)

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Do While Filename <> ""

Workbooks.Open (FolderPath)
numTest = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
MsgBox "Testing: " & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Cells(2, 1).Value & " is >= 5"
If numTest >= 5 Then
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1),   
Cells(erow, 10))
Else
MsgBox ("test1")
End If
Filename = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

I also figured out how to select a range to copy:

```
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
```

How could I change this so that only particular columns are copied?

Comment: Also  I  noticed that this doesn't work as I expected  `numTest = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value` I want it to take the value of in the master workbook its currently taking from the workbook with the macro.

Comment: Did you actually write this script?

Comment: Yes Dave, Obviously using parts that I have learned from online. I have to edit the above var numTest also so that the value entered is from the correct work sheet. P.s. Is it that bad? Also any declared unused variables where just pieces I had been testing with.

Comment: Appreciate your learning effort. To find out how to write a script, the first thing to do is to record a macro doing that action. See what excel records as script in the macro - and then fine tune it as required. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You still have a little way to go but it is not looking that bad :)

Here is some tips for you that will make it easier to write your code:

1. Store each worksheet as a variable, this makes it easier to see which sheet you are grabbing data from:

   ```
   Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbCurrent As Workbook

   Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
   Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath)
   ```
2. Name your worksheet in the master to make it easier to refer to (in VB hit F4 to see the sheet properties):

   ```
   numTest = wbMaster.SHEETCODENAME.Range("RANGENAME").Value
   lastrow = wbMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
   lastcolumn = wbMaster.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   ```
3. It will be easier for you if you have your master data stored as a Table, google this and see that cells and columns gets even more easy to reference.
4. Do a paste and copy in one go (it is best to never select any ranges while running a macro

   ```
   wbMaster.SHEETCODENAME.Range("A:A").Copy _
       Destination:=wbCurrent.SHEETCODENAME.PasteSheet.Range("B:B")
   ```
5. Check each row in a selected range:

   ```
   Dim rw As Range

   For Each rw In wbMaster.SHEETCODENAME.Range("RANGENAME").Rows
       'Do something
   Next rg
   ```